# DevExpress controls aren't setting the selected properties on PostBack/CallBack, if an original value was first set

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I'm currently testing with an ASPxDateEdit control and an ASPxComboBox control.

If I set the date or combobox selected item during page load, when I change the value of the controls during postback or callback, the value I get is the original value.

But if I don't set a previous value, the selected value returns as expected. I've set the date via the .Value, .Date, and .Text property. I set the combobox via .Value, .Text, FindByItem, and just plain looped through the items and matched up the items.

Anyone know what could be going wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my issue.

The problem was that I was setting the data during page load. When I did a postback or callback, that event fired again. So the data was changed to the original value.

The solution was to check for a non postback

if (!Page.IsPostback)

Comment: Accept your own Answer in order to close this Issue.